# Facebook Pixel ignoring 'AddToCart' event in click function

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

I am adding Facebook Pixel track events to an Online Shop. For some reason the following code gives an error on Facebook's Chrome Extension:

[image]

The code used is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_to_cart_button').click(function() {
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
            content_ids: [ '56404', '48061', '56412' ],
            content_type: 'product',
            value: 48,
            currency: 'EUR'
        });
    });
});
```

When the click event is removed the Facebook Chrome Extension tracks the 'AddToCart' event but ideally this is added on click of the 'Add To Cart' button not on load of the page otherwise my guess is that you end up with incorrect data.

Should I ignore this error or leave it without the click event?

Comment: Depending on what your button does, it might simply not have time to send the tracking request ... f.e. if your button submits a form that loads a new page.

Comment: Yeah that may be the reason why, the button refreshes the page - we should be able to change it to work with an ajax event instead.

Comment: @CBroe it looks like the event is still being fired. I managed to find the Pixel feed with the activity of each event, so I suppose we can ignore it.